# Map method in Ruby giving error

Tags: ruby, irb, ruby-1.9.3

```
"aaabbb".chars.to_a.permutation.map(&:join).uniq
```

works correctly and gives the desired output which is all the words that can be formed using the given string, but the same code fails if the string is "cdcdcdcdeeeef" or "cdefghmnopqrstuvw" instead of "aaabbb". I just tried for these three test cases as of now out of which three fail.

```
"cdefghmnopqrstuvw".chars.to_a.permutation.map(&:join).uniq
```

The above line of code just doesn't return any result. It seems like it goes into an infinite loop.

What's going wrong?

Comment: It just takes a looooong time to return the result of that piece of code.

Comment: MY IRB got hanged for you...:-(

Comment: I don't think it's taking a long time..it's hanging as Arup said. Just doesn't give any response.

Comment: @sawa Try in your IRB -`"cdefghmnopqrstuvw".chars.to_a.permutation.map(&:join).uniq`..

Comment: @sawa I didn't understand what you mean by cannot be reproduced?

Comment: It *does* take a long time. It's hanging/doesn't give a response, because it is computing the result. Which takes a loooooooooong time.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No result..it just sits there without giving any result..but as Boris and Mischa is saying it's taking a lot of time to caculate.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error..explained just above your comment what happens

Comment: You wrote that ruby is giving an error and/or fails.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please put the *exact* error message in your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are n! permutations of n elements. So if you have "cdcdcdcdeeeef" as an example, there are 13! = 6227020800 possible permutations, so it just takes a really long time to compute the result. Your other example has 17 character, which leads to 17! = 3.56 * 10^14 permutations, which will take "forever".

Edit:
A better solution would be to iterate over `"aaabbb".chars.to_a.permutation` and to create a result array yourself. To get `uniq`-functionality, you can check if the currently examined element is already in the result. However, this would only need less memory, but it would take as long, as your approach. I am afraid, there is no straight-forward to overcome this issue. In the worst-case, there is no way at all to speed up the calculation. If there are no duplicated characters, then the result must contain n! elements. However, if there are duplicated characters, there might be a way, but I don't know it.

Comment: So what is a better way to do this?

Comment: Notice that, just to store the results, you need at least 17 bytes * 17! = 6.04 * 10^15 bytes = 6.04 PB (peta bytes) of memory.

Comment: @gautam What's the end goal of doing this? You really don't want to be calling `permutation` on an array with more than say 11 elements in most cases in my opinion.

Comment: @JKillian I am solving a question on hackerank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-thrones) so was using this to solve that question.

Comment: @gautam Ah, I see where you were going with it, and what you thought of is a quite logical idea. But clearly, because of the time and space it uses, isn't a good final solution for this problem. So your challenge is to try to come up with a faster, 'smarter' solution :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not giving an error, and it's not an infinite loop either.

The calculation is just way too complex and it will take a while to solve it. I will explain why.

Say you have a single letter 'a'

There is one possible permutation for that letter

```
'a'
```

now, say you have two letters 'a' and 'b'

There are two possible ways of arranging these letters

```
'a, b' or 'b, a'
```

In your first example, you gave "aaabbb", which has 6 values.

There are 6x5x4x3x2x1 ways of arranging this or in other words

720 possible permutations

If you had 7 values, you would multiply the previous result by 7.

The higher up you get, the values increase exponentially.

In your second example, "cdefghmnopqrstuvw" I calculated 17 values.

That would be the equivilent of taking an array of all numbers from 1 to 17 inclusive

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
```

and then multiplying all of them

```
numbers.reduce(:*)

=> 355687428096000
```

This is the number of permutations in the string. To find all of them would take weeks.

Comment: @DarkMouse...Thank you for the explanation :)